# How to define to features after identifying problems

Tags: usability, interaction-design, user-behavior, user-expectation, design

Hi I'm an engineer new to UX, me and my startup team have identified problems for a market to solve. We have a good designer (who can make high fidelity interface designs) and were all familiar with Nir Eyals hook model, and we have engineering talent as well!

We ran into a problem with the team where after we identified our problems to solve and listed out potential solutions for those problems we needed to identify key features to make.

My question is what is a good process to identify which key features to make? What are tested methods to make this process a lot easier?

Comment: Can't you attach to each problem a metric?

Comment: "identified problems for a market to solve" - I don't quite understand are addressing market problems or interface problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could only suggest few methods which should help you figure out what are your key features.

**WHY IS IT IMPORTANT TO PRIORITIZE?**

‣ Focus on what adds value to the user’s experience.

‣ It’s much easier to extend existing behaviors than to force people into a completely new way of doing something.

‣ Focusing on what the majority of users are trying to do is important. Don’t get distracted by people who say you have to meet every single edge case... because you don’t.

**PRIORITIZATION METHOD 1: DOT VOTING**

‣ Ask people to vote based on how well the ideas address the problem statement.
‣ Creates a heatmap of a group’s concerns and priorities.

‣ Can be a popularity contest if voters aren’t aligned on theproblem.

[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot-voting

**PRIORITIZATION METHOD 2: MOSCOW**

‣ M: Must have this requirement to meet the business needs

‣ S: Should have this requirement if possible, but project success does not rely on it

‣ C: Could have this requirement if it does not affect anything else in the project

‣ W: Would like to have this requirement later, but it won't be delivered this time

**PRIORITIZATION METHOD 3: NOW NEXT LATER**

‣ A great way to lull stakeholders into a sense of security that they will get their features.

‣ Forces the team to prioritize in relation to goals.